# Proving Equivalence with Subtraction

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

I am in the process of learning Lean, and am working through a very simple example:

```lean
def toFin6 (n:Nat) : Fin 6 :=
  if p:n < 6 then { val := n, isLt := by exact p2 }
  else
    toFin6 (n - 1)
  decreasing_by
    simp_wf
    induction n
    /- n = 0 -/
    contradiction
    /- n > 0 -/
    sorry
```

I appreciate there are simpler ways of converting a `Nat` into a `Fin X` type.  But, that's not the point.  I'm stuck here, where the goal is effectively this:

```lean
theorem p (n:Nat) : Nat.succ n - 1 == n :=
by 
  sorry
```

Logically, it seems straightforward: `(n+1)-1 == n`.  Also, I'm aware that I can resolve this as follows:

```Lean
import Mathlib.Tactic.Linarith

theorem p (n:Nat) : Nat.succ n - 1 == n :=
by 
  simp
```

Ok, *but how to do it without `simp` and just using basic tactics in the Prelude?*  Seems like `Nat.succ_sub_one` could be useful here.

Comment: You could've seen what lemmas `simp` used by calling `simp?`.

Comment: Ok, that's handy!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did come up with this eventually:

```lean
theorem p (n:Nat) : Nat.succ n - 1 = n :=
by
  rw [Nat.succ_sub_succ]
  rw [Nat.sub_zero]
```

It was only via the VS code completion that I found those tactics.  Is there a list of them somewhere?

Comment: There is a whole list of all mathlib and otherwise lemmas in here: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/ You may also find loogle.lean-fro.org helpful.

Comment: So, mathlib is really the de facto library everyone uses?

Comment: Most users are mathematicians so the answer is "yes" but it might just be a historical coincidence that most users are mathematicians. Core Lean contains nothing beyond what is needed to compile core Lean. The standard library `Std` contains some stuff but is still very much in active development. Natural subtraction is a filthy idea though, and it wouldn't surprise me if mathlib is the place to look for if you want to use it. The nat subtraction in your definition in the question is a huge code smell.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Ok, how would you avoid natural subtraction in this example?  Would you retype the variable after the condition or something?

Comment: In this case, `else toFin6 5`